# Acumos project-service can't start

Tags: acumos

I run `oneclick_deploy.sh` of the `clio` release under docker on a VM that is accessible only by LAN. It successfully creates a number of containers, which all seem to be up and running apart from the `acumos_mlwb-project-service_1`, which constantly restarts and fails with the following error in docker logs:

> 2020-02-12T08:51:18.920Z  main    ERROR   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter          Error
>   starting Tomcat context. Exception:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException.
>   Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'handlerInterceptorConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'loggingHandlerInterceptor'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'appConfiguration': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'confProps'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'configurationProperties': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'couchdb.user' in value "${couchdb.user}"

I can access the portal, create a user, login, and begin to onboard a model, however all attempts fail with the following error in the frontend:

> Onboarding error details: Error transferring file: Connection refused
>   (Connection refused) Onboarding status: Failed

Any hints on what I might be doing wrong?